# the text input is not going full to right if is long

Tags: html, css

I want to create a login page, I created the input text where you should put your email address.
But, if the email is long, it remains a little spaces (i think of the padding-right).

My question is, how can I fix the text to be able to see to the end of the border?
I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

https://i.gyazo.com/eef966af3f6df3edc483b7077372c51a.mp4

Code:

```css
* {
  background-color: #4D6275;
}

.box_input_auth {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #2E3841;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 350px;
}

input[type=email] {
    color: white;
}

input[type=email]::placeholder {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">


<div class="email-input">
                <label class="label-icon-input"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-10x"></i></label>
                <input type="email" name="login_email" id="id_login_email" class="box_input_auth" placeholder="Email ID">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to decrease the padding-right and also if you want you can increase the width as I have done in the code below.**
**you can write it as**

```
.box_input_auth {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #2E3841;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 550px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Done. you had set the left padding to 100px...

```css
    * {
      background-color: #4D6275;
    }

    .box_input_auth {
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 1px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        outline: none;
        font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #2E3841;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 350px;
    }

    input[type=email] {
        color: white;
    }

    input[type=email]::placeholder {
        color: grey;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">


    <div class="email-input">
                    <label class="label-icon-input"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-10x"></i></label>
                    <input type="email" name="login_email" id="id_login_email" class="box_input_auth" placeholder="Email ID">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`padding-right` is the culprit:

```css
* {
  background-color: #4D6275;
}

.box_input_auth {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #2E3841;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}

input[type=email] {
  color: white;
}

input[type=email]::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">


<div class="email-input">
  <label class="label-icon-input"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-10x"></i></label>
  <input type="email" name="login_email" id="id_login_email" class="box_input_auth" placeholder="Email ID">
</div>
```